# Branding ForeFront TMG

Tags: html, inline-styles

Recently I've been asked to brand a couple clients' ForeFront TMG login screens, and I was rather shocked seeing it all being pure HTML and inline-styling.

Does there exist any tools aimed for **branding** the forefront TMG (I don't need to change any sentences or similar, only the layout of the page(s)). Or am I forced to open every single page and change the HTML and write inline-styling?

Thank you.

Comment: I think it depends on your structure of all the pages. But If I was you I would copy&paste the inline styling in an extern css file and put all the styling in an external file so you only would have to edit one and not 100..

Comment: @EvilP - But if I was to put all the styles in an external css file, I'd still have to edit all the pages in order to give all tables, divs etc. their respective css classes in order for it to take effect on all of them, correct? Or is there some kind of "masterpage" like in asp.net to TMG?

Comment: For my curiousity, how many pages are there? I'd have guessed only two: the login page and an error page. But it sounds like yes - if you can find the pages on disk and they aren't obviously generated from something that you have then you may have to edit them yourself. Are they easy to search / replace the styles at least?

Comment: @Rup - There are approximately 15 (including change password, forgot password, error pages etc.) Yes they should be quite easy to search/replace through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well let me just say this, I Googled "Forefront TMG", and found your problem!

> Microsoft Forefront Threat Management Gateway (TMG) 2010 allows your business to safely and productively use the Internet without worrying about malware ...
>
> #### Microsoft Forefront Threat...
>
> ### Microsoft Forefront...
>
> ## Microsoft...

So yeah, Microsoft loves doing that kind of stuff (not following standards or any known good practices known to man, blah blah blah), so that's probably the "logic behind ForeFront TMG".

---

As for your actual problem, I'm afraid you won't have much choice but to make an offline backup of the current pages, and reconstruct them (normally, like a sane, non-[cthulhu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cthulhu)-possessed, human being) with an external stylesheet.

Honestly, once you reconstruct page one, the rest should be much easier (since you already coded 80% of the CSS you need, all you are missing are some side CSS properties and class names).

Good luck!